# insert values from one column to another in same table - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert values into new column from existing column in same table (SQL) . (Both existing column and new column values should be same ).
Any Suggestions..

Comment: Hint:  `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

UPDATE table SET param1=newValue WHERE param2=criterion

Comment: This helped . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE it is, as you've already heard. A little bit of code:

Sample table and several rows of sample data:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (existing_column number,
  3     new_column      number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (existing_column)
  2  select level from dual connect by level <= 5;

5 rows created.

SQL> select * From test;

EXISTING_COLUMN NEW_COLUMN
--------------- ----------
              1
              2
              3
              4
              5
```

Let's update rows whose existing column's value is less than or equal to 3:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    new_column = existing_column
  3  where existing_column <= 3;

3 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

EXISTING_COLUMN NEW_COLUMN
--------------- ----------
              1          1
              2          2
              3          3
              4
              5

SQL>
```